# pulling data from multiple tables into 1 object

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I need to pull data from 2 tables into 1 object. Both tables share equipment number, and I need to get the corresponding description from table EQKT and the owner ID from EQUZ.

```
DATA: BEGIN OF t_report OCCURS 3,
matnr LIKE eqkt-equnr,
mtart LIKE eqkt-eqktx,
maktx LIKE equz-J_3GEIGNER,
END OF t_report.*-
DATA: d_repid LIKE sy-repid.

*-----------------------------------------
*--Selection Screen
SELECT-OPTIONS: s_matnr FOR eqkt-equnr.

*-----------------------------------------
START-OF-SELECTION.
*-Read data
  SELECT * FROM eqkt
  WHERE equnr IN s_matnr.
    CLEAR makt.
    SELECT SINGLE *
    FROM makt
    WHERE matnr = eqkt-equnr AND
    spras = sy-langu.
    MOVE: eqkt-equnr TO t_report-matnr,
    eqkt-eqktx TO t_report-mtart.
    APPEND t_report.
  ENDSELECT.

*This is where it stops working.
  SELECT * FROM EQUZ
  WHERE equnr IN s_matnr.
    MOVE: EQUZ-J_3GEIGNER TO t_report-maktx.
    APPEND t_report.
  ENDSELECT.
```

The code compiles, and in the ALV in which I display it, it does properly display the "owner" at the top of the table, but no data is filled in for the owner (the equipment number and description are properly displayed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second loop should not add new entries into the table, but it should rather fill the third column in the table, which was basically populated in the first loop, correct?

If this is so, move the second select into the first select, and do it the same way as you do it with table `MAKT`, namely

```
SELECT SINGLE J_3GEIGNER  
    FROM EQUZ
    INTO T_REPORT-MAKTX
    WHERE equnr = eqkt-equnr.
```

But if you want really to keep two loops, you need to use field-symbols in the second loop, like this:

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <T_REPORT> LIKE LINE OF T_REPORT.
SELECT * FROM EQUZ WHERE equnr IN s_matnr.
  READ TABLE T_REPORT ASSIGNING <T_REPORT>
         WITH KEY MATNR = EQUZ-EQUNR.
  CHECK SY-SUBRC EQ 0.  " skip unknown material numbers
  <T_REPORT>-MAKTX = EQUZ-J_3GEIGNER.
ENDSELECT.
```

This way the values from table `EQUZ` will be added to the proper record in the internal table `T_RECORD`.

Btw, one additional hint: do not use `OCCURS`, rather declare the tables explicitly. In your case it should be like this:

```
DATA: BEGIN OF S_report,
        matnr LIKE eqkt-equnr,
        mtart LIKE eqkt-eqktx,
        maktx LIKE equz-J_3GEIGNER,
      END OF S_report,
      T_REPORT like standard table of S_REPORT.
```

Of course, then you can't use header line, but use `S_REPORT` as work-area and for instance write `APPEND S_RECORD TO T_RECORD` instead of `APPEND T_RECORD` (but it will make your code only better and easier to read and maintain).

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is a JOIN:

```
SELECT T~EQUNR T~EQKTX Z~J_3GEIGNER 
  INTO TABLE T_REPORT
  FROM EQKT AS T
  JOIN EQUZ AS Z
    ON T~EQUNR = Z~EQUNR
  WHERE T~EQUNR IN S_MATNR
    AND T~SPRAS = SY-LANGU.
```

(In your example you don't have a field `MTART` defined in your table but you move it there in your code. You can of course just adjust this example as you need).